# Question on styling my links, what css to i need to get the desire look

Tags: html, css

This is how I placed my SignIn and Contact Links.

how do i increase the space been between the to links.
"Sign In" and "Contact"

```
const Header = () => (
  <div className = 'header'>‚
  <h1 className = 'title'>Title</h1>
  <div className="header-right">
      <Link className='link-buttons' to={"/login"}> Sign In</Link> 
       <Link className='link-buttons' to={"/login"}> Contact</Link>  
  </div>
</div>
);

export default Header;
```

How can I format them like buttons? I don't want them so close to each other.

Comment: Do you know about the `css` `margin`-property? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: i edited your q, and updated the code, to a more readable version.. easiest is you could literally place a space (&nbsp;) between the two.   https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with below css, hope it will work for you.

```css
.header-right a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin: 4px 8px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #027501;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```